# Unlock a screen in android using disableKeyguard

Tags: android

In my application I am using `disableKeyguard` and `reenableKeyguard` to Unlock and lock a screen. my application is working fine. But problem is when user unexpectedly unlocked a screen by dragging keygaurd (without using my application), the screen does't lock again with  my application.

How to solve this problem?

Thanks in advace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD` and/or `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` instead; this allows you to seamlessly hide the keyguard as your application moves in and out of the foreground and does not require that any special permissions be requested. Handle returned by `newKeyguardLock(String)` that allows you to disable / reenable the keyguard.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur replay. As u said I used Flag_Dismiss_keygaurd. It will disable keygaurds only when my application is in foreground. then how to use this?

Comment: can anybody help me in this issue??

Comment: use this....http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#newKeyguardLock(java.lang.String)